# webview resize after rotation

Tags: android, webview

I have webview on half size of the screen. If device  is rotation to horizontal position under content appears free space becouse content resize, but webview takes more than half of the screen, and not resize together with the text. How make resize webview?

UPD. Thank you for all! 
The problem is becouse of I use preference: android:configChanges="orientation" in manifest file. If off this option webview resize automatically.

Comment: refer to LinearLayout's `weightSum` param. Check this out http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/312

Comment: Problems with webview. Resize Layout does not work.

Comment: with `weightSum` you can control in kinda of percentage way the resizing process of your view. So say, 50% is webview and another 50% is the rest stuff. So whenever it requires to be stretched it will fill out the screen as 50/50.. or you may want to change it with 20/80 or whatever

Answer (score 0):

use this code for the **webview** to fit in your layout position.

```
    ourBrow.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    this.ourBrow.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
    this.ourBrow.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
```

Comment: I try this advice in the onCreate and onConfigurationChanged methods, but it does not work. What I do wrong?

Comment: Thank you for all! 

The problem is becouse of I use preference: android:configChanges="orientation" in manifest file. If off this option webview resize automatically.